# Printing until a specific character position in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

First I apologize if this is a question that has been answered many times, I searched around a while for an answer, but much of what I found went over my head since I am just beginning to learn python. But here's my question:

I want to print periods until the 20th character or column of the row so that the data to the right of the periods all line up as shown below.

```
--------------- 
HDL 
--------------- 
//============================================================ 
// USERID:........ ADET_ID 
// PROGRAMMER:.... Lname, Fname MI. 
// COURSE:........ CSCI-400 
// TERM:.......... SP14 
// PROJECT:....... 01 
// FILENAME:...... AnExample.hdl 
//============================================================
```

Here's what I currently have but how would I account for the periods without actually hard coding them in?

```
print("//", end = "")
for num in range (0,self.dividerLength):
    print("=", end = "")
print("\n", end = "")
print("// USERID:")
print("// PROGRAMMER:")
print("// COURSE:")
print("// TERM:")
print("// PROJECT:")
print("// FILENAME:")
return ""
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.ljust`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
>>> '// {} {}'.format('USERID:'.ljust(16, '.'), 'ADET_ID')
'// USERID:......... ADET_ID'
```

More simply using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with `fill` character specified (See [Format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)):

```
>>> '// {:.<16} {}'.format('USERID:', 'ADET_ID')
'// USERID:......... ADET_ID'
```

- `.`: fill character
- `<`: left alignment
- `16`: width of the result string

**Why 16?**

`20 - 4`

4 = 2 (for `//`) + 1 (space after `//`) + 1 (space after `.`)

Answer (score 1):

While you should use @falsetru's answer for any production code, if you're new to programming it's useful to learn how to do it 'manually':

```
DESIRED_SIZE= 10 #size of the final string we want
s= "USERID"      #our initial string
n= DESIRED_SIZE-len(s) # how many characters must we add
#create a string with n "." characters
#on a lower-level language (like C) you'll need to use a loop to do this
padding= "."*n   
result= s+padding
print result
```

this prints `USERID....`